# Simulate tap in iOS webview with button

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, tap

I am trying to build an app for people with disabilities who are unable to use gestures such as swipe and pinch. I realise there is no way to simulate taps inside iOS however is it possible to somehow send a a tap event to a webview so they could control the internet.

Perhaps this can be done with Javascript?

I have looked on this subject for some time but cannot find any answers.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: jQuery plugin to trigger events: https://github.com/FGRibreau/jQuery-plugin-fireEvent

Answer (score 1):

You will need to inject Javascript into the `UIWebView` (using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`). Your Javascript will then need to simulate the events that you want to inject, using `document.createElement` etc. I think injecting `jQuery`  and plugins is a bit overkill (the `UIWebView` will always be a modern WebKit for starters), but if you feel inexperienced in web technology that's of course a viable way. A library that's especially targeted to simulating touch events is [thumbs.js](http://mwbrooks.github.io/thumbs.js/).

Otherwise, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events) is the canonical starting point when starting to learn about DOM events.

You'll need to inject your 'agent' code into every URL the `UIWebView` visits. I've had luck with doing this in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`.